# How to organize CRUD for table with composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, crud

I have a table to store simple parameters in format *param name* / *param value*. But it primary key is composite key.

What is the best way to organize adding/updating/deleting parameters with locking. So for example if someone start putting into table next parameters

```
first_comp_id   second_comp_id  paramName   paramValue

12              5               param_1     sdgfsdf
12              5               param_2     sdgfsdf
12              5               param_3     sdgfsdf
12              5               param_4     sdgfsdf
```

Anyone else cannot add/edit or delete any record with {first_comp_id:12, second_comp_id:5} ?

Below my table structure (I slightly changed names but idea the same):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable](
[first_comp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[second_comp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[paramName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[paramValue] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY 
    (
    [first_comp_id] ASC,
    [second_comp_id] ASC,
        [paramName] ASC
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if i got this correctly you have user1 entering those records 
and user1 can edit them and add new records with {first_comp_id:12, second_comp_id:5}

you would need to add a col containing a unique reference to the user

then you would in your code accessing the db add the check that the user has to be correct

```
update sometable (paramValue) where first = ee and second = bb and name = rr and user = current user
```

insert would become

```
IF not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE  first = ee and second = bb and name = rr and user <> current user)
BEGIN
   insert into sometable (first,second, name, val, user)
  values (ee,bb,rr,vv,uu) 
END
```

or if you want it completely on db level you could use triggers 
before update check if correct user

before insert check if first and second aren't used by another user